# Frame didn't arrived within 5000 while reading .bag file - pyrealsense2

Tags: python, realsense, rosbag

I'm trying to read the frames in the `.bag` files with `pyrealsense2`. I followed the [read_bag_example](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/examples/read_bag_example.py) by Intel. Here's the full sample that the code that I'm using.

```
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import os
import time
import cv2

i = 0
try:
    config = rs.config()
    rs.config.enable_device_from_file(config, "D:/TEST/test_4.bag", repeat_playback=False)
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()
    pipeline.start(config)

    while True:
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
        if not depth_frame:
            continue
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())

        color_image = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

        cv2.imwrite("D:/TEST/image/" + str(i) + ".png", color_image)
        i += 1
finally:
    pass
```

The code is working. However I checked the number of frames via `realsense-viewer` and its output is **890** frames. However, the output of this code always changes in the **range of 500-770** and raise the error:

> RuntimeError: Frame didn't arrived within 5000

I searched lots of hours but I was not able to find a solution that would resolve my problem.

I'm also using

- Intel Firmware version - 5.11.15.0
- Python - 3.6.8
- pyrealsense2 - 2.24.0.965
- D435 with **848x480, 90 FPS** images

I could add more information if you need. Any help or other suggestions would greatly appriciated!

Comment: I am facing a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/q/63027477/2478346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is about the **playback time** of the `pyrealsense2`. Modules automatically assign it as if they are **real-time**. Setting a profile, and setting playback time resolved the problem. There is a sample code that works with the **848x480-90FPS**  below.

```
i = 0
try:
    config = rs.config()
    rs.config.enable_device_from_file(config, "D:/TEST/test_4.bag", repeat_playback=False)
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()
    profile = pipeline.start(config)
    playback = profile.get_device().as_playback()
    playback.set_real_time(False)

    while True:

        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        playback.pause()
        depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
        if not depth_frame:
            continue
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())

        color_image = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        cv2.imwrite("D:/TEST/image/" + str(i) + ".png", color_image)
        i += 1
        playback.resume()

except RuntimeError:
    print("There are no more frames left in the .bag file!")


finally:
    pass
```

As could be seen above, while loop changed slightly in order to ensure that the gathered frame first processed before taking a new frame with the `playback.pause()` and `playback.resume()`.

**TL;DR:**

You should set `playback.set_real_time(False)` if you are getting inconsistent number of frames in a `.bag` file.

Comment: Thanks for this, just what I was looking for. Surprisingly,  using `playback.pause()` and `playback.resume()` breaks my code(only reads one frame), and I cat get by just using `playback.set_real_time(False)`. BTW where in the real-sense viewer can I see the number of frames in the bag file?

Comment: Actually, I could not find something that shows the number of frames in realsense-viewer. While I'm using the pyrealsense, I have experienced that one code may not work in some PC's. Maybe that's why you are having problem with pause and resume. One other reason might be your `playback.pause()` and `playback.resume()` are not inside the same while loop.

Comment: thanks for replying. You're right there is no way to see the number of frames in a bag file. For that we need to use `rs-rosbag-inspector`.

Comment: I'll see my code if the `.pause()` and `.resume()` are in the same code block